# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839494/please-help-please) I put a helpful comment linking to Meta's faq about accepting answers. I went to look this morning and the comment is no where to be found though

The comments part of the question where I posted it:
[alt text http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7296/commenty.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/7296/commenty.png)

but in my recent activity:
[alt text http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/1807/activity.png](http://img571.imageshack.us/img571/1807/activity.png)

Comment: As an aside: at most *one* `@reply` will result in a notification, but the person you're commenting on will always be notified, so does not need a `@reply`. Hence, dropping the `@` before `@davit` ensures `@Darin` will yield a notification for Darin. All fun details at [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [comment is there](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2839494/comments) – the only thing missing is the "get more comments" link. That occurs sometimes, because the comment count on posts is denormalized. When the wrong number of comments is recorded for the post, it can happen (like in this case) that you don't get the link to retrieve more comments, even though there are such.

IIRC, there's a cron job running to look through things like this, so it will probably be fixed within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

That is a trainwreck of a question, so I just deleted it to clean up.

Comment: so @balpha is wrong? You actually did delete it?

Comment: @earlz I deleted the *question* much later. your comment was not deleted, it's still there if you have 10k rep to see the deleted question.

Comment: Ah ok, so balpha was right then but the question is now deleted so it doesn't matter anyway